# How could this "Out of Memory" error have happened?

Tags: flutter, dart

Yesterday, I ran into a Memory Leak and I don't understand why.

I am using GetX for Statemanagement.

I have a GetXController called "EditContentController"  in which I "load" an Object into, in order to cache changes that are made, while the user edits this object.

```
class EditContentController extends GetxController {

  TextEditingController titleController;
  TextEditingController descriptionController;
  int newCompletionGoal;
  List<int> newSchedule = [];
  DateTime newCompletionDate;

  @override
  void onInit() {
    titleController = TextEditingController();
    descriptionController = TextEditingController();
    super.onInit();
  }

  @override
  void onClose() {
    titleController.dispose();
    descriptionController.dispose();
    super.onClose();
  }

  void loadHabitValues(Habit habit) {
    titleController.text = habit.title;
    descriptionController.text = habit.description;
    newCompletionGoal = habit.completionGoal;

    for (var i = 0; i < habit.scheduledWeekDays.length; i++) {
      newSchedule.add(habit.scheduledWeekDays[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

When the user presses a "Save" button, these new values get applied to the Object, otherwise, the cached information is discarded.

The code above lead to the following problem: When I first loaded a "Habit" object into this controller, all the values got populated as intended.

The second time I loaded a "Habit" to this controller, it gave me an "Out of Memory" exception.

I was able to locate the error :

```
    //habit.scheduledWeekDays has a maximum of 7 integers
    for (var i = 0; i < habit.scheduledWeekDays.length; i++) {
      newSchedule.add(habit.scheduledWeekDays[i]);
    }
```

this for loop was adding data to a list, that already had values. So the first time I loaded the object, the list got filled. The second time, the new data was added on top.

I was able to fix this with this method:

```
    newSchedule.clear();
```

which I am now calling before I load an object. But it leaves me wondering:

How can something trivial as a list, that had a max of 7 integer numbers cause an "Out of memory" exception, when another maximum of 7 integers get added ?

Am I missing something?